# Use Ramda to change deep nested object value

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have the data structure like below, how can I use Ramda to change the `quantity` as number type to string type (from `1` to `"1"` )

```js
const data = {
  orderInfoList: [
    {
      orderNo: "string",
      productList: [
        {
         productName: "string",
         quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you need to use ramda for it?

Comment: If you just want the value at those specific instances, then you could write `over (lensPath (['orderInfoList', 0, 'productList', 0, 'quantity']), String) (data)`, but if not, I don't think there's anything built into Ramda that will help very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to perform this transform on all products in every order:

```js
// Utility function
const mapOver = R.curry(
  (lens, Fn, ent) => R.over(
    lens, 
    R.when(R.is(Array), R.map(Fn)), 
    ent
  )
);

const transformProductQuantity = R.over(
  R.lensProp('quantity'), 
  String
);

const transformOrderProducts = mapOver(
  R.lensProp('productList'), 
  transformProductQuantity
);

const transformData = mapOver(
  R.lensProp('orderInfoList'), 
    transformOrderProducts
);

const data = {
  orderInfoList: [
    {
      orderNo: "1",
      productList: [
        {
         productName: "Foo",
         quantity: 1
        },
         {
         productName: "Bar",
         quantity: 12
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      orderNo: "2",
      productList: [
        {
         productName: "Foo",
         quantity: 12
        },
         {
         productName: "Bar",
         quantity: 15
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      orderNo: "3",
    }
  ]
}

const result = transformData(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```